# Nautilus launchers stopped working properly

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, unity

I have been trying to make a launcher with a quicklist item for 'root file browser' using command 'gksudo nautilus'. After I updated to this launcher in the unity sidebar, each time I click the icon (which still points to the normal nautilus for left click) a separate nautilus icon appears elsewhere in the sidebar with the title 'Files'. I really want it to appear under the same icon in the sidebar. I copied the `nautilus-home.desktop` from `/usr/share/applications`.

Here is the contents of the `nautilus-home.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=File Browser
Comment=Open your personal folder
Exec=nautilus
Icon=user-home
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Core;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=nautilus
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=general
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.0.0
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nautilus

X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Root

[Root Shortcut Group]
Name=Root File Browser
Exec=gksudo nautilus
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the 9th line in your .desktop - "OnlyShowIn=Gnome;Unity;", then probably do a log out/in

Comment: Can you explain why this works? All the tutorials I have seen include this. Unfortunately, I am on away from the computer for two days so will get back when I can test it.